# How to get the signup event response in Meteor with accounts-ui?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using `accounts-ui` with `{{> loginButtons}}` for sign up and login functionalities. After user sign up I want to get response along with user data. How can I get the signup event response?

Comment: you can listen for create user callback on the server `Accounts.onCreateUser` or `Accounts.onLogin`

Comment: @ Mark Uretsky : Is it possible to call from the client side. Also is there any function that I can implement after creating a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`accountsServer.onCreateUser(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) hook, which will be called whenever a new user is created:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
        console.log(user);
        return user;
    });
}
```

The returned `user` will be inserted into the [`Meteor.users`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users) collection.

Here is a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/444JjerzY82KtMkv2/Leaderboard-Accounts-Ui).